# Angular 8 refresh/reload showing Not found [Deployment]

Tags: angular, deployment, subdomain, angular7, cpanel

I deployed a laravel project which is working just fine, but when i navigate and try to refresh or reload it throws a Not Found server error.

Answer (score -1):

After a little research, i figured out multiple ways to solve this. 
First:  Setting the useHash option to true in the app.routing module

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, **{ useHash: true }**)],
```

Next, create a .htaccess file in the root directory of the domain/subdomain, and paste the below code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine on

        # Don't rewrite files or directories
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]

        # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow HTML5 state links
        RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I would go for the ‘next’ option.. hashes are ugh..

Comment: @MikeOne can you kindly answer the question with your suggested solution? thank you

Comment: Oh sorry, the solution is there, the htaccess rewrites are what is needed to make this work..

Comment: ok @MikeOne . Kindly upvote my answer if it worked for you too